# BackupPC Can't create a test hardlink

Tags: backuppc

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

BackupPC used to backup to an external USB drive which was mounted auto at boot. For some reasons now is not mounted and I did not change /etc/fstab

I changed /etc/default/grub to disable GUI, I mean to boot the in text mode and suddenly I encounter this error. Actually, there was no grub in /etc/default and I renamed /etc/default/grub.bak to /etc/default/grub.bak
Can grub have anything to do with the error described below? If not why I got this error?

```
Can't create a test hardlink between a file in /var/lib/BackupPC//pc
and /var/lib/BackupPC//cpool.  Either these are different file systems,
or this file system doesn't support hardlinks, or these directories don't exist, or there is a permissions problem, or the file system is
out of inodes or full.  Use df, df -i, and ls -ld to check each of
these possibilities. Quitting...
```

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't provided any OS & release links. It might also help if you explain what you mean by changed grub to boot in text mode (grub itself is always in text; it can be dressed up a little by varying font, colors & background - but it's still text).  If you're instead trying to mention a changed runlevel, kernel option etc. please be specific.

Comment: it was an ownership issue, now OK